# Как отключить прокрутку вверх страницы при нажатии на ссылку <a href = '?id= echo $id; echo "</a>">?

Tags: javascript, html

Есть модуль новостной ленты. Расположен под шапкой сайта.[image: введите сюда описание изображения] 50% от блока занимает список новостей, остальные 50% описание выбранной новости. Когда пользователь кликает по новости справа генерируется её описание, но при этом страница прокручивается в самое начало. При использовании "event.preventDefault()" или "return false" прокрутка пропадает, но $id новости не передаётся. Как можно реализовать генерацию описания новости без прокрутки страницы в начало?

```
 //HTML разметка
<section id="news">

      <div class="news_content">

        <img class="title_news" src="images/news.png">

          <?php 

            if (!empty($_SESSION['user_id'])) {
              echo '<div class="rss">
                      <div class="news_feed">';

              require_once ('php/news_generator.php');

              echo '  </div>
                      <div class = "more">';

              require_once ('php/news_description_generator.php');

              if (isset($_GET["id"])) {
               display_news_description($_GET["id"]);
              }

              else {
                display_latest_news();
              }

              echo '  </div>
                    </div>';
            } 

            else {
              echo '<div class="rss">';
              include('php/stubs/news_feed_stub.php');
              echo '  </div>';
            }

          ?>

      </div>

    </section>

//Генератор новостей
<?php

require_once ('conn_db.php');

$limit = 10;

$date_of_publication = 'нет данных';
$views = '0';
$comments = '0';

$query = "SELECT * FROM news_feed ORDER BY `id` DESC LIMIT " .$limit;

$result  = $pdo -> query($query);
$row = $result -> fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

if(is_array($row) ) {

    foreach($row as $array) {

        global $id;
        global $small_image;
        global $news_title;

        $id = $array["id"];                                                                 
        $small_image = $array["title_image"];
        $news_title = $array["title_text"];

        include ('templates/news_template.php');

    }
}

?>

//Генератор описания для новостей
<?php 

require_once('conn_db.php');

function display_news_description($id) {

    global $pdo;

    $where = "WHERE `id` = " . $id;
    $query = "SELECT * FROM news_feed $where ORDER BY `id` DESC LIMIT 1 ";

    $result = $pdo->query($query);
    $row = $result->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

    foreach ($row as $array) {

        global $midle_image;
        global $intro_text;
        global $id;

        $id = $array["id"];
        $midle_image = $array["midle_image"];
        $intro_text = $array["intro_text"];

        include('templates/description_template.php');
    }

}

function display_latest_news() {

    global $pdo;

    $query = "SELECT `id` FROM `news_feed` WHERE `id`";

    $result = $pdo -> query($query);
    $row = $result -> fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

    $last = array_key_last($row);
    $id = end($row[$last]);

    $query = "SELECT * FROM `news_feed` ORDER BY $id";

    $result = $pdo -> query($query);

    foreach ($result as $array) {
        $midle_image = $array['midle_image'];
        $intro_text = $array['intro_text'];
    }

    include('templates/description_template.php');

}

//Шаблон для новости
<?php 

  echo " <a href='?id="; echo $id; echo "'class='item one'>

        <img src='"; echo $small_image; echo " ' alt='#'>

        <div class='article_info'>

            <p class='news_title'> ";echo $news_title; echo "  </p>

            <ul>

                <li>
                    <img src='images/rss/icons/publication_ date.png' alt='#'>
                    <p>"; echo $date_of_publication; echo " </p>
                </li>

                <li>
                    <img src='images/rss/icons/views.png'alt='#'>
                    <p>";  echo $views; echo "</p>
                </li>

                <li>
                    <img src='images/rss/icons/comments.png' alt='#'>
                    <p>";  echo $comments ; echo "</p>
                </li>

            </ul>

        </div>
    </a> ";

?>

//Шаблон для описания новости
<img src="<?php echo $midle_image ?>" alt="#">
<p> <?php echo $intro_text ?> </p>
```

Comment: может вы покажете код ? или мы угадывать будем ?

Comment: windows.scrollBy()